# How to pass params from one app to another app using Linking in react-native 0.59

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native.

I want to pass params from one app to another app using Linking in react-native

Here is my code in `Send_params_app`

```
 Linking.openURL(redirecturl).catch((err) => {
    console.log("err------*", err);
    Linking.openURL("https://apps.apple.com/in/app/....?q=dsfsdfdsf");
  });
```

Here code for `Get_params_app` in `App.js` file

```
        import { Linking } from "react-native";

        export default class App extends Component {

            handleAutoLogin = () => {
                Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
                    if (url) {
                        console.log('paramsparamsparamsparams=======>>>>>', url);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("No Parameter found, perform any other operation");
                    }
                }).catch(err => console.error('Silently capture the error', err));
            }

            render() {
                this.handleAutoLogin();
            }
        }
```

Using this code I successfully redirect to another app but When `handleAutoLogin` function call every time it's give `null`

**I am using `react-native 0.59.5` version** That's problem ??

Help me thanks..

Comment: Some apps like Google Maps and Mail have built-in deep linking support. You need to examine the deep linking support of your target app

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel thanks... But how to implement built-in deep linking in target app ?

Comment: It depends on target app, those app developers provide deep linking  API.

Comment: Look Google Map for instance - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel actually I have made the target app also :)

Comment: Consider to read this article - https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-deep-linking-in-react-native/